# .Net 6 framework not found on target machine

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am experiencing the following issue:

- Installed .Net 6 SDK on my development machine and created an executable using Visual Studio 2022 (using .Net 6):
  [image]
- Installed .Net 6 Runtime on target machine:
  [image]

However, when I try to run the executable I get this error:
[image]

Comment: how are you running it? it looks like you need the windows desktop runtime

Comment: you can also publish the runtime with the app

Comment: it is an EXE file generated with VS 2022, just double-clicked on it to run. What is windows desktop runtime?

Comment: Can you please add more details: how do I "publish runtime with the app"?

Comment: Visit the [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0), click on the installer for ".NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.8", x64.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: But I did that already, I also added a screenshot showing .Net 6 runtime is installed on the target machine, please see above

Comment: Hmmm, published as self-contained, folder is now 300 MB as opposed to 2 MB if I publish as framework-dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confuse you, Microsoft publishes many different versions of the .NET 6 runtime. There are versions for ASP.NET hosting, Console applications and Windows desktop. You need to ensure that the desktop version is installed.